# Getting dynamically added textbox value in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, class, dynamic, textbox

When I creating input elements in Angular, it did not give a value property. Or any other property unless I do it manually. And after that, it won't update it. Getting elements by ClassName and saying `.getAttribute("value")` will only return its initial value.

I've set the value property manually with `node.setAttribute("value","")`. Typing in the `textbox` will show what you type, but console logging that elements value only shows it's initial value. It works with `getElementsByTagName` but I can't use that

**Creating text boxes**

```
var node;
for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
  node = document.createElement("input")
  node.setAttribute("class", "input");
  node.setAttribute("value", "");
  document.getElementById("boxesDiv").appendChild(node);
}
```

Inside a keydown event to check values of boxes after typing in them

```
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('input');
for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
  if (arr[index].getAttribute("value") != "") {
    filledCount++;
    console.log("count++")
  }
}
```

Expected it to console log "count++" when it sees a `textbox` has a value/something in it.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this in Angular Way as follows.**

```
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

export class YourComponent {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  countFilledInputs(): void {
    let arr = this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('input');
    let filledCount = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
        if (arr[i].value !== "") { 
          filledCount++; 
        }
    }
    console.log("Filled Input Count => " + filledCount);
  }
}
```

**[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-56780757?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: The whole thing is going on a keydown event binding, which doesn't let me use any non-default functions or whatever they're called. I can't use ElementRef because the document itself doesn't understand what it is